# What is the metric for testing item-item similarity?

Tags: recommendation-engine, collaborative-filtering

For item-item collaborative filtering, the similarity score between two items is `sim(x,y) = dot(x,y)/(norm(x)*norm(y))`. But how do you check if the result you get is accurate?

Answer (score 0):

Different similarity measures may return different results. For instance; one's appearance may be more similar to his father than his mother and on the other hand his attitude may be more similar to his mother than his father. So in this case, which similarity measure is more accurate? They are both accurate from different perspectives.

**Accuracy depends on prediction (MAE, RMSE, etc.) and the recommendation results (precision, recall, etc.)**. In order to find best similarity measure for data set, you should try different similarity measures on same conditions.